# Configure Pure-FTPd to limit access to FTP to some IP?

Tags: ftp

Is there any way to limit connection to FTP, to allow only connection from certain IP, or range of IPs if Pure-FTPd is installed on server.

Something like .ftpaccess, ftp access configuration file? But .ftpaccess does not work with Pure-FTPd?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a firewall like iptables to filter ip addresses connecting to the ftp port. If you are using debian or ubuntu, look into ufw firewall. ufw is extremely simple to use.

Comment: I have centos. Can you provide me with more details how and where to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to run Pure-Ftpd through a super-server like xinetd
or tcpserver.

Then you must configure the allowed IP in `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TCP Wrappers to Restrict Access to your desired services.
Required files to edit, are one of below files.

> /etc/hosts.allow
>
> /etc/hosts.deny

You may search for the syntax in the internet.